# How should I send userdata to jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, user-data

ok, here is the thing ... I've this jqGrid and what I need is to sumarize showed data. This jqGrid has definitions as shown bellow

```
jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid
    { 
        url:'/loadGrid.php?q=2', 
        datatype: "xml", 
        colNames:[...], 
        colModel:[...], 
        // some other params.
        footerrow : true, 
        **userDataOnFooter : true,** // it should show footer's custom information.
        altRows : true
    }).navGrid('#pagerGrid',{add:false,edit:false,del:false, search:false});
```

and loadGrid.php has the next structure shown bellow

```
$page = $_GET['page']; // get the requested page 
$limit = $_GET['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction 

// here goes connextion to database and data collection
...
//

if ( stristr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"],"application/xhtml+xml") ) 
{
    header("Content-type: application/xhtml+xml;charset=utf-8"); 
} 
else 
{
    header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");
}

$et = ">";
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?$et\n";
echo "<rows>";
echo "<page>$current</page>";
echo "<total>$total</total>";
echo "<records>$records</records>";

// and data population
foreach( $data as $key => $value ) 
{ 
    $ff = $value['field_1'];
    echo "<row id='". $ff."'>";
    // $ff = $value['field_1'];
    echo "<cell> <![CDATA[" . $ff . "]]></cell>";
    $ff = $value['field_2'];
    echo "<cell> <![CDATA[" . $ff . "]]></cell>";
    $ff = $value['field_3'];
    echo "<cell> <![CDATA[" . $ff . "]]></cell>";
    // ... and so on whith all column definitions.
    echo "</row>";
}

echo "</rows>";
```

This works but the problems becomes when show the grid. In the footer of the grid I only see an empty row. If I put some sumarized data and try to send to the page it doesn't show anything. So, What I need to know is how should I pass userdata for the page to read it.

I'd already read information from jqGrid whiki and said something like 
*"userData: This array contain custom information from the request. Can be used at any time."* but I cann't figure how to pass this information to #myGrid. 
Does somebody has any idea about it? Any help will strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format of user data in XML can looks a little strange at the first look, but it is clear documented [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#user_data). You should add some XML elements in the form

```xml
...
<page>1</page>
<userdata name="gridColumName1">value1 in the summary</userdata>
<userdata name="gridColumName2">value2 in the summary</userdata>
...
```

You should use the same column names ('gridColumName1', 'gridColumName2') like you as defined in the `name` property of columns definitions in the `colModel`.